# Laravel 5.6: intl-tel-input compatibility issue with App.js

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, intl-tel-input

I have a Laravel 5.6 web page and I want to add IntlTelInput 
(https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) but I have try to install it from source, composer and npm (currently using composer and mix to copy build folder) and the 3 of them seem to not initialize the plugin.
[image: Example]

- It's not my browser (have try with many and it works in codepen)
- I have Jquery installed
- I included the stylesheet
- I override the path to flags.png in my CSS (In HTML and in app.scss [and run npm run watch])
- I added the intlTelInput.js script after the input
- I initialized the input with `<script>$("#phone").intlTelInput();</script>` (After the input in DOM)

This is what I got from inspecting the result:

```
    <div class="intl-tel-input allow-dropdown">
       <div class="flag-container">
          <div tabindex="0" class="selected-flag">
             <div class="iti-flag"></div>
             <div class="iti-arrow"></div>
          </div>
          <ul class="country-list hide">
             <li data-dial-code="1" data-country-code="us" class="country preferred">
                <div class="flag-box">
                   <div class="iti-flag us"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="country-name">United States</span><span class="dial-code">+1</span>
             </li>
             <li data-dial-code="44" data-country-code="gb" class="country preferred">
                <div class="flag-box">
                   <div class="iti-flag gb"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="country-name">United Kingdom</span><span class="dial-code">+44</span>
             </li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
             <li data-dial-code="93" data-country-code="af" class="country ">
                <div class="flag-box">
                   <div class="iti-flag af"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="country-name">Afghanistan (‫افغانستان‬‎)</span><span class="dial-code">+93</span>
             </li>
             <li data-dial-code="355" data-country-code="al" class="country ">
                <div class="flag-box">
                   <div class="iti-flag al"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="country-name">Albania (Shqipëri)</span><span class="dial-code">+355</span>
             </li>
             <li data-dial-code="213" data-country-code="dz" class="country ">
                <div class="flag-box">
                   <div class="iti-flag dz"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="country-name">Algeria (‫الجزائر‬‎)</span><span class="dial-code">+213</span>
             </li>

....

                <span class="country-name">Western Sahara (‫الصحراء الغربية‬‎)</span><span class="dial-code">+212</span>
             </li>
             <li data-dial-code="967" data-country-code="ye" class="country ">
                <div class="flag-box">
                   <div class="iti-flag ye"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="country-name">Yemen (‫اليمن‬‎)</span><span class="dial-code">+967</span>
             </li>
             <li data-dial-code="260" data-country-code="zm" class="country ">
                <div class="flag-box">
                   <div class="iti-flag zm"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="country-name">Zambia</span><span class="dial-code">+260</span>
             </li>
             <li data-dial-code="263" data-country-code="zw" class="country ">
                <div class="flag-box">
                   <div class="iti-flag zw"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="country-name">Zimbabwe</span><span class="dial-code">+263</span>
             </li>
             <li data-dial-code="358" data-country-code="ax" class="country ">
                <div class="flag-box">
                   <div class="iti-flag ax"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="country-name">Åland Islands</span><span class="dial-code">+358</span>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </div>
       <input name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" value="9992715671" required="required" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
```

When I manually remove the hide class from ul class="country-list hide" it then appears but I can't interact with it, it appears that the js is not working properly I guess.

What happens if I remove the "hide":

[image: No Hide Class]

**UPDATE:**

Doing more testing I realized that if I comment out the "*app.js*" script intl-tel-input works perfectly so my question is now, what do I have to change in App.js to make this work? (I haven't added nothing to app.js, it is the same one that comes with every laravel installation)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after installing via yarn.
My solution was to add the following:

`require('intl-tel-input/build/js/utils');
require("intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput");`

To `./resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` right after `require('bootstrap');`

And then to add:

`jQuery( '#phone' ).intlTelInput({
    dropdownContainer: 'body',
    autoPlaceholder: 'polite',
    initialCountry: 'auto',
    geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
        jQuery.get("https://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
            var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
            callback(countryCode);
        });
    },
});`

to the end of the file `./resources/assets/js/app.js`

**Note** I added some arguments to mine, since I was also having issues with the automatic country detection until I sorted this out.

Comment: I tried this but seems not to work. I got `intlTelInput is not a function` error.

Comment: Same issue Here. Did anyone resolved this some how?

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing the defer attribute but got this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app
```

Try moving your `app.js` import after the body tag. This will solve the issue.

```
<body>...</body>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```